# Precalculate data vs sequential processing

Tags: c++, c, caching, optimization

I have the following sequential code:
1.

```
ProcessImage(){
    for_each_line
    {
        for_each_pixel_of_line()
        {
            A = ComputeA();
            B = ComputeB();
            DoBiggerWork();
        }
    }
}
```

Now I changed for precalculating all the A, B value of whole image as below.
2.

```
    ProcessImage(){
       for_each_line
       {
           A = ComputeAinLine();
           B = ComputeBinLine();
           for_each_pixel_of_line()
           {
                Ai = A[i];
                Bi = B[i];
                DoBiggerWork();
            }
        }
    }
```

The result shows that the 2nd block of code execute slower about 10% of processing time compared to the 1st block of code.

I wondering was it a cache miss issue in the 2nd block of code ?

I am going to use SIMD for parallel the precalculation in the 2nd block of code. Is it worth trying ?

Comment: Are you profiling with optimizations enabled?

Comment: Are you compute- or memory-bound?

Answer (score 1):

All depends on how did you implement your functions. Try to profile your code and determine where are the bottlenecks.

If there are no benefits in calculating values once for a row, then don't use it. You need A and B values only for one pixel routine. In the second block of code you run the line once for calculate values, then run again for `DoBiggerWork()` and each time you retrieve values from prepared array. That costs more CPU time.